# how to listen the change the value in textfield or textbox in j2me?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I want to store each character that is input from user. When user presses key, that key should store in any variable. When user presses other key, it must replace the value of variable with new character in textbox in j2me

Comment: the editing really change the scope of question,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you need to listen event ***ItemStateListener*** and then you can handle it in ***itemStateChanged(..)*** Here is full code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package hello;

import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

/**
 * @author Jigar
 */
public class KeyEventListener extends MIDlet implements ItemStateListener{

    private boolean midletPaused = false;

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Fields ">
    private Form form;
    private TextField textField;
    //</editor-fold>

    /**
     * The KeyEventListener constructor.
     */
    public KeyEventListener() {
    }

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Methods ">
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Method: initialize ">
    /**
     * Initilizes the application.
     * It is called only once when the MIDlet is started. The method is called before the <code>startMIDlet</code> method.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        // write pre-initialize user code here

        // write post-initialize user code here
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Method: startMIDlet ">
    /**
     * Performs an action assigned to the Mobile Device - MIDlet Started point.
     */
    public void startMIDlet() {
        // write pre-action user code here
        switchDisplayable(null, getForm());
        // write post-action user code here
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Method: resumeMIDlet ">
    /**
     * Performs an action assigned to the Mobile Device - MIDlet Resumed point.
     */
    public void resumeMIDlet() {
        // write pre-action user code here

        // write post-action user code here
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Method: switchDisplayable ">
    /**
     * Switches a current displayable in a display. The <code>display</code> instance is taken from <code>getDisplay</code> method. This method is used by all actions in the design for switching displayable.
     * @param alert the Alert which is temporarily set to the display; if <code>null</code>, then <code>nextDisplayable</code> is set immediately
     * @param nextDisplayable the Displayable to be set
     */
    public void switchDisplayable(Alert alert, Displayable nextDisplayable) {
        // write pre-switch user code here
        Display display = getDisplay();
        if (alert == null) {
            display.setCurrent(nextDisplayable);
        } else {
            display.setCurrent(alert, nextDisplayable);
        }
        // write post-switch user code here
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Getter: form ">
    /**
     * Returns an initiliazed instance of form component.
     * @return the initialized component instance
     */
    public Form getForm() {
        if (form == null) {
            // write pre-init user code here
            form = new Form("form", new Item[] { getTextField() });
            form.setItemStateListener(this);
        }
        return form;
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Getter: textField ">
    /**
     * Returns an initiliazed instance of textField component.
     * @return the initialized component instance
     */
    public TextField getTextField() {
        if (textField == null) {
            // write pre-init user code here
            textField = new TextField("textField", null, 32, TextField.ANY);

        }
        return textField;
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /**
     * Returns a display instance.
     * @return the display instance.
     */
    public Display getDisplay () {
        return Display.getDisplay(this);
    }

    /**
     * Exits MIDlet.
     */
    public void exitMIDlet() {
        switchDisplayable (null, null);
        destroyApp(true);
        notifyDestroyed();
    }

    /**
     * Called when MIDlet is started.
     * Checks whether the MIDlet have been already started and initialize/starts or resumes the MIDlet.
     */
    public void startApp() {
        if (midletPaused) {
            resumeMIDlet ();
        } else {
            initialize ();
            startMIDlet ();
        }
        midletPaused = false;
    }

    /**
     * Called when MIDlet is paused.
     */
    public void pauseApp() {
        midletPaused = true;
    }

    /**
     * Called to signal the MIDlet to terminate.
     * @param unconditional if true, then the MIDlet has to be unconditionally terminated and all resources has to be released.
     */
    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(Item item) {
        if(item.equals(getTextField())){
            System.out.println("KeyPressed :) ");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply 
but how can i use this in netbeans 
plz reply

Comment: You are always welcomed to mark this as answer as it is for you.